# Successive json & jsonp requests fail using Crossrider?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsonp, crossrider

I'm using crossrider to implement a cross-browser plugin.

I've two successive AJAX requests (JSON and JSONP):

1. The first is a JSON request for "login" which sets a cookie in
   browser.
2. The second is a JSONP request for "save" which saves some data to server using the cookie.

Here's a simplified example of the code:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url : "https://app.testafy.com/api/v0/user/login", 
    type : 'GET', 
    cache : false, 
    dataType : 'json', 
    data : {login_name: "abashir", password: "P@ssw0rd"} 
}).done(function(response) { 
    alert("Login Success"); 
    $.ajax({ 
        url : 'https://app.testafy.com/api/v0/test/save', 
        type : 'GET', 
        cache : false, 
        dataType : 'jsonp', 
        data : {"pbehave":"For+the+url+http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F%0D%0A","title":"test","description":" "} 
    }).done(function(response) { 
        alert("Saving Success:\n\n" + JSON.stringify(response, undefined)); 
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("Saving Failure:\n\n" 
            + JSON.stringify(jqXHR, undefined) + "\n\n" 
            + JSON.stringify(textStatus, undefined) + "\n\n" 
            + JSON.stringify(errorThrown, undefined)); 
}); 
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    alert("Login Failure:\n\n" 
        + JSON.stringify(jqXHR, undefined) + "\n\n" 
        + JSON.stringify(textStatus, undefined) + "\n\n" 
        + JSON.stringify(errorThrown, undefined)); 
});
```

It works very well for IE, FF & Chrome, if it's in an HTML (auto-login then auto-save).

But when placed in a crossrider extension.json (in appAPI.ready), it gives three different behavior in each browser.

**For Chrome:**

- Login terminates successfully.
- Saving fails with output:

> {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}
>   "parseerror" 
>   {}

**For Firefox:**

- Login terminates successfully.
- A popup asks for credentials (as if the cookies weren't set by login !!)
- after entering the credentials (abashir & P@ssw0rd)
- Saving fails with output:

> {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}  
> "parseerror"  
> {}

**For IE9:**

- Login fails with output:

> {"readyState":0, "setRequestHeader":{},....,"statusText":"No Transport"}  
>  "error" 
>  "No Transport"

PS, using fiddler, i noticed that in chrome the response returned from the server is correct (despite that ajax fail function is called), here's the request/response pair from fiddler:

**REQUEST:**

```
GET https://app.testafy.com/api/v0/test/save?callback=jQuery17107044411341194063_1364461851960&pbehave=For%2Bthe%2Burl%2Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fstackoverflow.com%252F%250D%250A&title=test&description=+&_=1364461865618 HTTP/1.1 
Host: app.testafy.com 
Connection: keep-alive 
Accept: */* 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22 
Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/ 
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8 
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3 
Cookie: __utma=124963983.2014233417.1360749029.1362583015.1362996135.12; __utmc=124963983; __utmz=124963983.1362322761.9.3.utmcsr=stackoverflow.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; GSG_SESSIONID=ee03a02cdb6f3c0e3d812795be63c788
```

**RESPONSE:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 nginx 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Date: Thu, 28 Mar 2013 09:03:48 GMT 
P3P: CP="ALL ADM DEV PSAi COM OUR OTRo STP IND ONL" 
Set-Cookie: GSG_SESSIONID=ee03a02cdb6f3c0e3d812795be63c788; domain=app.testafy.com; path=/; secure; HttpOnly 
Content-Length: 273 
Connection: keep-alive 

jQuery17107044411341194063_1364461851960({"test_id":"558","message":"Phrase check has found the following error(s), but your test was still saved:\nThere's no For rule for '+the+url+http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F%0D%0A'\n\nSaved new test as id#558","project_id":"151"});
```

As you may noticed, the call of the generated callback function contains the right json object, despite the fail function is called back ! And this response cannot be accessed to extract the data from it !

**How to make the previous 2 successive requests work on the 3 browsers (IE, FF, Chrome) using crossrider ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the issue relates to cross-domain restrictions encountered when using $.ajax from within the Extension scope.

You can avoid this issue by using our [appAPI.request.post](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.request-method-post) method per the example code below. The code was tested in Chrome, and both the login and save succeeded.

Let me know if you need any further assistance with this.

```
appAPI.ready(function ($) {
    appAPI.request.post({
        url : "https://app.testafy.com/api/v0/user/login",
        onSuccess: function (response) {
            alert("Login Success");
            appAPI.request.post({
                url : 'https://app.testafy.com/api/v0/test/save',
                onSuccess: function (response) {
                    alert("Saving Success:\n\n" + appAPI.JSON.stringify(response));
                },
                onFailure: function (httpCode) {
                    alert("Saving Failure:\n\n" + httpCode);
                },
                postData : {
                    "pbehave" : "For+the+url+http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F%0D%0A",
                    "title" : "test",
                    "description" : " "
                }
            });
        },
        onFailure: function (httpCode) {
            alert("Login Failure:\n\n" + httpCode);
        },
        postData: {
            login_name : "abashir",
            password : "P@ssw0rd"
        }
    });
});
```